# How to get the highest resolution, dividable by 2 that contains the video without black borders after rotation?

Tags: ffmpeg

I rotate a video. Then my goal is to get the biggest resolution, dividable by 2 that contains the video without black borders.

[image: rotated and bigger]

to

[image: rotated, smaller and dividable by 2]

My approach.

```
ffmpeg -ss 6 -i "t.MP4" -ss 0 -t 5 -vf "rotate='8*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow', scale='1920:1920', crop='1920:1080:0:420'" -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -acodec copy "t2.MP4"
```

But that does not meet the criteria. Which command do I need?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i t.mp4 -vf "rotate=8*PI/180:ow=rotw(8*PI/180):oh=roth(8*PI/180), \
                     crop=iw-2*imgh*sin(8*PI/180):ih-2*imgw*sin(8*PI/180): \
                     imgh*sin(8*PI/180):imgw*sin(8*PI/180), \
                     scale=iw:-2"
       -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -acodec copy "t2.MP4"
```

For anti-clockwise rotation, add a -ve sign to the angles in the rotate filter, but not in the crop filter.

In the commands above, `imgw` and `imgh` stand for the width and height of the source image and have to be explicitly supplied i.e. for a 1280x720 video, where it says `imgw`, you should supply `1280`.